# How to correct this loop?

Tags: r

```
lottery<-replicate(200,sort(sample(x=1:49,size=6,replace=FALSE)))

duplicated(t(lottery))

a<-matrix(c(lottery,nrow=6))     

answer<-c(16,11,24,26,15,18)

total<-0

for(i in 1:200)
 {
     correct <- 0
     special <- 0
      
       for(j in 1:6)
          {
              for(k in 1:7)
               {
                   if(a[j,i] = answer[k])
                     {
                         correct <- correct+1
                         if(k <- 7)special <- 1
                       }
               }
           }
```

it shows error. How to correct it? I want to set a loop for winning lottery. I don't know where I wrong.

Comment: in addition to the problems mentioned below, you have `k` from `1:7` but `answer` is only length 6; also you are not storing any of the output, so it is being overwritten on each iteration. if you need the number correct, a more r-like solution would be `table(colSums(a == sort(answer)) == 6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues with your code. First, you are creating a one-dimensional matrix and you are trying to run if statement on two-dimensional matrix. Next, your basic syntax is wrong. Please read basic programming with R first. You need to understand how to create logical checks for if statements. ie. `==` vs `=`